# SQL: Is there a way that a REGEXP in sql query will return all data

Tags: sql, pdo

Hi guys i just want to ask if is there any way a regexp command in sql query can return all data? my problem is i have a query that will return data base on the regexp value, but i want to return all if the regexp value is null. for example

```
$stmt = prepare("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE position REGEXP ?");
$stmt->bindparam(1,$position);
$stmt->execute();
```

So my goal is to return all customers no matter the position is if the value of $position is null. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE to give null column a value:

```
WHERE COALESCE(position, 'x') REGEXP ?
```

If position is numeric, replace `'x'` with 1 ...

Comment: if none numeric?

Comment: Erm. What about `'x'`